# How do I get Marie to talk to me again?

Tags: persona-4-golden

My social link with Marie (Aeon) is currently at Rank 4. I am in August 2nd and am on summer break. According to [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/persona4goldenguide/social-links/aeon), Marie is available on Wed/Sat/Sun and all holiday days but not on rainy days. It also states that Rank 5 becomes available after July 24th. Since July 24th, there's only been one rain day, but she's never appeared outside the velvet room. If I go in the velvet room and speak to her, she says something along the lines that I (the protagonist) am busy right now and she doesn't want to talk to me.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to get her to spend time with me again?

Comment: The link also says re-entering the velvet room. Did you try just going out and back in if she says you're busy?

Comment: @ChaseC I did actually multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She will not talk to you until after Rise Kujikawa joins your party. Even the link you shared states that.

Comment: Rise is in my party.

Comment: Have you been back in the TV to replay Rise's mission? You just need to keep moving the story along and she'll show up. Be sure to check each day right away though. If you go to talk to her too late she wouldn't be available because her segments typically take the rest of the day. She'll be standing on the street outside the door when she's ready. Talking to her in the TV doesn't count.

Comment: In fact.. you were almost right. I had to move the story along and rescue the boy before she would show up again. It wasn't so much to do with Rise. Marie wouldn't show up as long as there is someone needing to be rescued (as well as the other criteria as well).

Comment: Huh. I don't remember mine working like that. Well, I'm glad you got it sorted out though.

Comment: It just happened again. She stopped coming out of the room on the days when she should be. This is right after the disappearance event on the 15th of September and I haven't yet rescued the victim.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've already saved the victim. If the victim has not been saved, you can't
progress in her social link.